# Sending a pdf from asp c# script based on a cookie setting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to only allow the download of a pdf based on a cookie setting.  I found an asp script that send a pdf file and wish to add a cookie check to it.  I cannot figure out the correct syntax to get it to work.

This code send the pdf fine:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.TransmitFile("test.pdf");
        Response.End();        
%>
```

I added this cookie check, but I keep getting a runtime error:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies["CHECK"];
if (mycookie != 'ok') {
 Response.Write('<html><body>you cannot see this pdf');
} else {
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.Clear();
 Response.TransmitFile("test.pdf");
 Response.End();        
}
```

%>

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of `mycookie` to see if it equals 'ok'.  You're checking if the object equals a string.  I'm assuming you're getting an invalid cast exception or something like that.

You want to check `if(mycookie.Value != 'ok') { ... }`